# Overloading a function in multilevel inheritence in PHP that doesn't take any arguments

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP, just started with the intermediate level. Below is the class hierarchy -

```
FamilyTree
    |
    |
Grandparents
    |
    | 
Parents
```

`Parents` have an extra property called `$dob` the rest are inherited from `Grandparents`

I was able to overload `set_values()` because they differed in the number of arguments, how do I overload `display_values()` since it doesn't take any argument?

This is the code :

```
<?php  

class FamilyTree {

    protected $name;
    protected $sex;
    protected $married;
    protected $number_of_kids;

    public function display_values() {
        echo $this->name            . "<br />";
        echo $this->sex             . "<br />";
        echo $this->married         . "<br />";
        echo $this->number_of_kids  . "<br />";
    }
}

class Grandparents extends FamilyTree {

    public function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids) {
        $this->name           = $name;
        $this->sex            = $sex;
        $this->married        = $married;
        $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
    }       
}

class Parents extends Grandparents {

    private $dob;

    public function __call($function_name, $arguments) {
        if($function_name == 'set_values' && count($arguments) == 5) {
            $this->$name          = $name;
            $this->sex            = $sex;
            $this->married        = $married;
            $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
            $this->dob            = $dob;
        }
    }
}

$gp = new Grandparents();
$gp->set_values("James", "Male", 'yes', 5);

$p = new Parents();
$p->set_values("Samuel", "Male", 'yes', 2, '2/5/1974');

$gp->display_values();
```

Comment: So what happens if you just add `public function display_values()` to `Parents` class?

Comment: @u_mulder, If I do that then it doesn't print anything for **$this->dob**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you, but you were unsuccessful in "overloading" that method.

If you take a closer look at your implementation if `__call`:

```
public function __call($function_name, $arguments) {
    if($function_name == 'set_values' && count($arguments) == 5) {
        $this->$name          = $name;
        $this->sex            = $sex;
        $this->married        = $married;
        $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
        $this->dob            = $dob;
    }
}
```

you will notice that

- `$this->$name` should be `$this->name`
- `$name`, `$sex`, `$married`, `$number_of_kids` and `$dob` are all undefined, and should instead be `$arguments[0]` to `$arguments[4]`.

But your `__call` implementation doesn't get called at all, because [PHP simply discards too many arguments to user-defined functions](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13892).

What you can do instead, is override the function and call the parent implementation with `parent::`:

```
public function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids, $dob = '') {
    parent::set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids);
    $this->dob = $dob;
}
```

I'm just initialising `$dob` to an empty string because it would default to `NULL` otherwise.
As a side note, if you want to offer a new implementation that takes *less* arguments than the original one, you can also do that with default arguments:

```
public function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids = 0) {
    parent::set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids);
}
```

which could then be called with either 3 or 4 arguments.

For more complex combinations, declare your new implementation with a default argument for every parameter (in order to make it compatible with the parent implementation) and use [`func_get_args`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) to handle or redirect the call.

Overriding `display_values` is simple though, since the number of arguments is just the same:

```
public function display_values() {
    parent::display_values();
    echo $this->dob . "<br />";
}
```

So in full, your code would look like this:

```
<?php  

class FamilyTree {

    protected $name;
    protected $sex;
    protected $married;
    protected $number_of_kids;

    public function display_values() {
        echo $this->name            . "<br />";
        echo $this->sex             . "<br />";
        echo $this->married         . "<br />";
        echo $this->number_of_kids  . "<br />";
    }
}

class Grandparents extends FamilyTree {

    public function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids) {
        $this->name           = $name;
        $this->sex            = $sex;
        $this->married        = $married;
        $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
    }
}

class Parents extends Grandparents {

    private $dob;

    public function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids, $dob = '') {
        parent::set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids);
        $this->dob = $dob;
    }

    public function display_values() {
        parent::display_values();
        echo $this->dob . "<br />";
    }
}

$gp = new Grandparents();
$gp->set_values("James", "Male", 'yes', 5);

$p = new Parents();
$p->set_values("Samuel", "Male", 'yes', 2, '2/5/1974');

$gp->display_values();
$p->display_values();
```

Answer (score 0):

For method overloading signature and method name should have to be same. Without these two it would not considered as method overloading. In this case , is is not overloading , but a separate method. You can simply overload by this display_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids) and set all values

Comment: It doesn't take any arguments I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood you, in this instance you are not overrloading set_values via __call in class parent. To overload, the method must be inaccessible.

```
class Parents extends Grandparents {

private $dob;

public function __call($function_name, $arguments) {
    echo 'called';
    if($function_name == 'set_values' && count($arguments) == 5) {
        $this->$name          = $name;
        $this->sex            = $sex;
        $this->married        = $married;
        $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
        $this->dob            = $dob;
    }
}
```

}

This will not print 'called' for $p->set_values("Samuel", "Male", 'yes', 2, '2/5/1974');.

To override the method the parent method must be inaccessible, it doesn't matter about the number of arguments, see this example:

```
    <?php

class FamilyTree {

    protected $name;
    protected $sex;
    protected $married;
    protected $number_of_kids;

    private function display_values() {
        echo $this->name            . "<br />";
        echo $this->sex             . "<br />";
        echo $this->married         . "<br />";
        echo $this->number_of_kids  . "<br />";
    }
}

class Grandparents extends FamilyTree {

    private function set_values($name, $sex, $married, $number_of_kids) {
        $this->name           = $name;
        $this->sex            = $sex;
        $this->married        = $married;
        $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
    }

    private function drawMe($a)
    {}

}

class Parents extends Grandparents {

    private $dob;

    public function __call($function_name, $arguments) {
        echo 'Args: ' . count($arguments);
        echo ' | Function name: ' . $function_name;
        if($function_name == 'set_values' && count($arguments) == 5) {
            $this->$name          = $name;
            $this->sex            = $sex;
            $this->married        = $married;
            $this->number_of_kids = $number_of_kids;
            $this->dob            = $dob;
        }
    }
}


$p = new Parents();
$p->display_values();
echo '<br><br>';
$p->set_values("Samuel", "Male", 'yes', 2, '2/5/1974');
```

This prints:

Args: 0 | Function name: display_values

Args: 5 | Function name: set_values